# How to calculate the growth rate of a growing annuity?

Tags: finance

I have a question that seems basic but has given me fits. If I have the following known variables, how do I solve for the growth rate?

Known variables:

- initial payment
- outstanding balance
- number of periods

I need to solve for growth rate of payment where the cumulative value equals the outstanding balance...  assume a zero discount rate (i.e. interest free)

Example:

If I have a goal to save 20k in cash, and my initial saving per period is 1k, what is the growth rate per period required to reach 20k if I only make 17 deposits?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a basic finance question and this site is dedicated to professionals/academics in quantitative finance. You can try your luck in forums dedicated to the CFA curriculum, for example.

Comment: The summation for an annuity-due is `s = Σ a (1 + r)^k for k = 1 to n` which, by induction, has the closed-form `s = (a (1 + r) (-1 + (1 + r)^n))/r`.  Solving for `r` where `20000 = (1000 (1 + r) (-1 + (1 + r)^17))/r` finds `r = 0.0177995`